# Laravel Uploading file Direct to API server without saving it on hosting server

Tags: laravel, forms, xmlhttprequest, vimeo-api

I tried to search it everywhere but i couldn't find my answer. Here is the case

I have a form in Laravel,
User can upload video through this form.
The video is going to be saved/upload on **VIEMO** by API call.

Now what I want is, I don't want to save the video on my server, i.e I don't waent to save it on hosting app server
I want to directly send it to the **VIEMO** API but I am not sure how do I directly send it.
SO far this is the code

```
$video = $request->file('video');
dd($video);
Vimeo::connection('main')->upload($video);
```

Can somebody guide me how do i send this video coming through HTTP POST method directly to api.

Thank You

Comment: Could you try `Vimeo::connection('main')->upload($video->path());`, instead of passing the `UploadedFile` instance, pass the temporary file path instead.

Comment: @Remul I tried it and it worked, Thank you :)

Comment: it is still going to your server first then being uploaded to the api, btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing a `UploadedFile` instance to `upload()`, try passing the temporary file path:

```
Vimeo::connection('main')->upload($request->file('video')->path());
```